# Unable to create object of XMLType using Jdbctemplate

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbctemplate, xmltype

I am using Jdbctemplate for database connectivity. I am able to perform all database related operation. But unable to create object of type XMLType. Below are reference library regarding it.

[image]

Code to create XMLType object is:

```
XMLType xmldoc = new XMLType(dataSource.getConnection(), xml);
```

dataSource is data source for jdbctemplate operation. xml is string representation of xml document.

While debugging getting following page at that point. Please help me to resolve mentioned issue.
[image]

Comment: Please check if your JDBC driver is correct. Based on [Oracle JDBC FAQ](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/faq-jdbc.html#01_02) you should have for JDK 8 driver `ojdbc8.jar`

Comment: It would be also helpfull to post the *exception* you got while creating the `XMLType`

Comment: Tried with Ojdbc8 but no luck. And added exception block but not hitting to exception block. Controls stuck on the line where XMLType object creation code is present.